# Power bi bar chart issue

Tags: bar-chart, powerbi

I am new to Power bi and would appreciate some help. I have the datasource attached and am able to create a table view that shows the correct data.

[image]

When I try to switch the data to a bar chart using these settings:

[image]

I get these results:

[image]

Why are the columns the same value? The count of each type is certainly different.

Added:
The following is the data relationships. There are three separate databases and several tables related with mostly id numbers.

[image]

Comment: Are the two columns from the same table? If not, do they have a correct relationship?

Comment: Added relationship diagram

Comment: Which table(s) are `InstitutionType` and `SyStudentId` from?

Comment: It was a relationship issue, thanks

Comment: Someone should answer so I can give credit